# Git branching strategy - Pull requests create merge commits that make branches look different while the files are equal

Tags: git, pull-request, branching-and-merging

In my current project we have three branches; `master`, `dev` and `hotfix`.

When a new feature is to be implemented, a developer will create a new `feature_branch` from `master`. When the feature is ready for review and testing, the developer will create a pull request to merge the `feature_branch` into `dev`. When that is merged, the dev and test environments will be built and deployed (from the `dev` branch). In this environment there will be some testing and QA made.

Once the testing is complete, the developer will open a pull request from the `feature_branch` into `master`. After the merge to `master`, the build and deploy to staging and production will start.

This works fine, the only issue is that the different merge commits made by the pull request merges makes it so that the branches look different. In the branch view in Azure DevOps (which is our DevOps environment), the `dev` branch seems to be 1 commit behind and 1 commit ahead of the compare branch (which is the `master` branch). This is because the `dev` branch has a commit that the master branch does not have (the merged PR from the `feature_branch` into `dev`), and missing one that the `master` branch has (the merged PR from the `feature_branch` into `master`).

**Is there a good way to make the `dev` and `master` branches appear equal here?**

The idea behind these three branches is that if there is a bug, we can create a `bugfix_branch` from the `master` branch and open a pull request from the `bugfix_branch` into the `hotfix` branch. Merges into the `hotfix` branch will build and deploy a test environment in which the bug fix can be tested separately. Once the bug fix is approved, the developer will open a pull request from the `bugfix_branch` into `master`.

The `hotfix` branch will also appear different from `dev` and `master`.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose the following history:

```
* 99a48ee (feature_branch) Add feature a
* 499665a (HEAD -> dev, master) Initial commit
```

A merge from feature_branch to dev will create a merge commit:

```
git merge --no-ff feature_branch
```

```
*   8aa6422 (HEAD -> dev) Merge branch 'feature_branch' into dev
|\  
| * 99a48ee (feature_branch) Add feature a
|/  
* 499665a (master) Initial commit
```

> Once the testing is complete, the developer will open a pull request from the feature_branch into master.

That's the unconventional bit. You'll end up with the following:

```
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff feature_branch
```

```
*   9a3f2e7 (HEAD -> master) Merge branch 'feature_branch'
|\  
| | *   8aa6422 (dev) Merge branch 'feature_branch' into dev
| | |\  
| |/ /  
|/| /   
| |/    
| * 99a48ee (feature_branch) Add feature a
|/  
* 499665a Initial commit
```

This is already looking wrong! `dev` is now `[ahead 1, behind 1]` because it's including 8aa6422 and missing 9a3f2e7.

```
  dev            8aa6422 [ahead 1, behind 1] Merge branch 'feature_branch' into dev
  feature_branch 99a48ee [behind 1] Add feature a
* master         9a3f2e7 Merge branch 'feature_branch'
```

Rather than merging feature branch into master, one should have merged dev into master. Let's try this with the state of the repository before the latest merge above.

```
git reset --hard HEAD^  # rollback the merge we just did above
git merge --no-ff dev
```

```
*   c59be01 (HEAD -> master) Merge branch 'dev'
|\  
| *   8aa6422 (dev) Merge branch 'feature_branch' into dev
| |\  
|/ /  
| * 99a48ee (feature_branch) Add feature a
|/  
* 499665a Initial commit
```

That looks better, no overlapping lines! `dev` is no longer both ahead and behind, it's just behind, since it doesn't have the merge to master.

```
  dev            8aa6422 [behind 1] Merge branch 'feature_branch' into dev
  feature_branch 99a48ee [behind 2] Add feature a
* master         c59be01 Merge branch 'dev'
```

They're not the same, but they're only behind, so that will merge cleanly in the future if you do the same thing.

If you really want them to be the same, you'll need to fast forward merge instead of creating a merge commit. Let's rewind again and see what that looks like:

```
git reset --hard HEAD^  # rollback again
git merge dev           # without --no-ff will default to --ff (fast forward)
```

```
*   8aa6422 (HEAD -> master, dev) Merge branch 'feature_branch' into dev
|\  
| * 99a48ee (feature_branch) Add feature a
|/  
* 499665a Initial commit
```

Now master and dev are identical!

```
  dev            8aa6422 Merge branch 'feature_branch' into dev
  feature_branch 99a48ee [behind 1] Add feature a
* master         8aa6422 Merge branch 'feature_branch' into dev
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast and thorough response! Our idea behind the unconventional bit you mentioned is that we may have several feature branches merged into dev for testing at the same time. One or more of these features might not pass the QA/testing. So instead of having to wait for everything in the dev branch to pass QA (and also having to stop merging anything else into it for a period of time), we figured we could just merge the code that has passed QA/test into master right away. If you have suggestions on how we could solve this in a better way, I'd be happy to hear it!